# Multiple entities on one screen

Tags: jhipster

All the examples I find for JHipster is for applications that have a one to one relationship between entities and screens.

I would like to have more than one entity being controlled by one screen.

Is there any example of this?
Is there a best practice?

I don't mind hand coding, but if I start to hand code I want to follow some best practice.

I normally google for this, but all the examples are too simple: one-to-one examples.

Comment: Here I just posted a way I did it:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/40348923/6742558](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40348923/6742558)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a full jhipster example with multiple entities per screen, you probably won't find one. You got to search by underlying technologies: angular, jackson, spring mvc and you'll find richer examples.

Few tips:

- angular-ui router multiple named views per state can help
- consider aggregating REST resources on server to avoid multiple requests per screen